# Synchronizing 2 processes using interprocess synchronizations objects - Mutex or AutoResetEvent

Tags: c#, .net, synchronization, pinvoke, mutex

Consider the following scenario: I'm running my application which, during its execution, has to run another process and only after that 2nd process finishes inner specific initialization, can my first process continue. E.g:

```
...
// Process1 code does various initializations here
Process.Start("Process2.exe");
// Wait until Process2 finishes its initialization and only then continue (Process2 doesn't exit)
...
```

I see several options:

1. **Mutex** - Mutex comes to mind automatically when considering interprocess communication, however, I can't see a way of causing Process1 to wait for a mutex that he generated himself. I can cause Process2 to create a mutex and wait on Process1 till the Mutex is created (using polling and Mutex.OpenExisting function)
2. **AutoResetEvent** - Those would be perfect for the task, however, in seems that under .NET these can't be used for interprocess communcation.
3. **CreateEvent** - I can use P/Invoke and use Win32 CreateEvent function. In theory, it could provide me with everything I need. I'd rather not using native functions, however, if possible.
4. **Use external file** - The easiest way would be just to use some OS external object (file, registry, etc). However, this seems rather hacky, however.

I'd be happy to hear your opinion for this case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was just going to edit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4123979/975724), but it doesn't seem correct.  So I'll post my own...

According to the [Threads for C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx) page, which has a lot of synchronization tutorials, [`AutoResetEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) cannot be used for interprocess synchronization.

---

However, a named [`EventWaitHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.EventWaitHandle(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used for interprocess synchronization.
In the above page, visit the [Creating a Cross-Process EventWaitHandle](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_CrossProcess_EventWaitHandle) section.

The way you set this up is straight-forward:

- Create an [`EventWaitHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.EventWaitHandle(v=vs.110).aspx) in process 1, before starting process 2.
- After starting process 2, invoke [`EventWaitHandle.WaitOne`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx) to block the current thread.
- Lastly, create an [`EventWaitHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.EventWaitHandle(v=vs.110).aspx) in process 2 and invoke [`EventWaitHandle.Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set(v=vs.110).aspx) to release the waiting thread.

**Process 1**

```
EventWaitHandle handle = new EventWaitHandle(
    false,                                /* Create handle in unsignaled state */
    EventResetMode.ManualReset,           /* Ignored.  This instance doesn't reset. */
    InterprocessProtocol.EventHandleName  /* String defined in a shared assembly. */
);

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Process2.exe");
using (Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    //Wait for process 2 to initialize.
    handle.WaitOne();

    //TODO
}
```

**Process 2**

```
//Do some lengthy initialization work...

EventWaitHandle handle = new EventWaitHandle(
    false,                           /* Parameter ignored since handle already exists.*/
    EventResetMode.ManualReset,          /* Explained below. */
    InterprocessProtocol.EventHandleName /* String defined in a shared assembly. */
);
handle.Set(); //Release the thread waiting on the handle.
```

Now, regarding the [`EventResetMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventresetmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Whether you choose `EventResetMode.AutoReset` or `EventResetMode.ManualReset` depends on your application.

In my case, I needed a manual reset because I have have many processes connecting to the same process.  So, once this *same process* is done being initialized, all of the other processes should be able to do work.  Thus, the handle should be left in a signaled state (no reset).

For you, an automatic reset might be helpful if you have to perform initialization for every time *process 1* starts *process 2*.

---

**Side note:**  The `InterprocessProtocol.EventHandleName` is just a constant wrapped up inside a DLL that both *process 1* and *process 2* reference.  You do not need to do this, but it protects you from mis-typing the name and causing a deadlock.

Answer (score 10):

i would consider **AutoResetEvent **. they can be used for interprocess communcation and they are relativley fast.
see the following link: [Threads for c#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx)

read the Creating a Cross-Process EventWaitHandle section...

Comment: AutoResetEvent can be only local. But you're right - EventWaitHandle is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Why cant AutoResetEvent and ManualResetEvent be used for inter process communication?  They both derive from EventWaitHandle