# How can I tie together the lifetime of two processes in C#?

Tags: c#, process, desktop-application

I have an application that instantiates two distinct processes in C#. Let them be A and B.

Usually, launching A would launch B under the hood. Because of a product bug on a specific version, for that faulty version I need to use a workaround based on launching process B first and then process A on top of it.

Everything works fine functionality-wise, but closing A won't close B this way. Because B ends up having no window when A comes into play, it cannot be nicely closed after closing A (if it could, I wouldn't have this problem) and must be killed with task manager.

Is there any way I can tie together the two C# `Process` objects, so that closing A would trigger the closing of B?

**Note:** Killing them inside the app I'm writing is not an option, because user must decide when the A & B ensemble gets closed

Comment: Are you fixing this in compiled code or are you tweaking a "batch" file launcher process to get B to start first.

Comment: @SqlSurfer compiled code. `Process` objects that instantiate `.exe`s

Comment: If B should always close if A is closing than add code to B that self shuts down if it does not see A running for more than 10 seconds.    If you have to tie the instances together than use a command line param or the process ID to know which one is "owned" by the one that started the other process.  In effect make both A and B smart.  The top "window" handle or process id can be used as an ID  to tie them together.   I would look into a process C that manages all this.  (Detail - .NET "classic" and .NET core behave a little differently when launching processes.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use inter-process communication techniques and classes like **named** system mutexes,  [EventWaitHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandle.-ctor), sockets, etc. A very similar question and solution can be found on another [stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123923/synchronizing-2-processes-using-interprocess-synchronizations-objects-mutex-or)

```
public EventWaitHandle (bool initialState, System.Threading.EventResetMode mode, string? name, out bool? createdNew);
```

> name
> String
> The name, if the synchronization object is to be shared with other processes; otherwise, null or an empty string. The name is case-sensitive.